# Android Data Binding : Using the @={} syntax for two data binding causes the Binding file not to be generated

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to use the 2 way data binding feature of the android 2 way data binding library .

My gradle version is

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
}
```

When I use the library for simple binding it works

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_view_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Enter Username"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="@{model.username}"
        />
```

When I use the `@={}` format for the 2 way data binding it doesnt work

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_view_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Enter Username"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="@={model.username}"
        />
```

It doesnt work  . I get the following error

```
Error:(9, 31) error: package databinding does not exist
```

Basically the databinding classes arent getting generated . Please help In  case any other information is required let me know .

```
public class Login implements IBaseModel {
    public String username, password;

    public Login(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }
}
```

and the view model class is

```
public class LoginViewModel implements IViewModel {
    private Subscription subscription;
    private ILoginDataListener dataListener;
    private Login login;

    Context context;


    String getUserName() {
        return this.login.getUsername();
    }

    LoginViewModel(Context ctx, Login login) {
        this.context = ctx;
        this.login = login;
    }

    public void onClickSubmit(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "From View Model username is " + this.login.getUsername() + " the password " + this.login.getPassword(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Toast.makeText(context, "From View Model", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        loginRequest("Rajendra", "12345");
    }

    public void updateValue(View view) {
        this.login.password = "dummy";
        this.login.username = "simplefool";
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

        if (subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) subscription.unsubscribe();
        subscription = null;
        context = null;
        dataListener = null;    
    }
}
```

Comment: post your model class

Comment: In case I need to update gradle sdk tools or android studio . Please let me know . Currently Android studio is 2.2.1 , the gradle version is :gradle:2.2.1  and androidBuildToolsVersion = '24.0.1'

Comment: public class Login implements IBaseModel {
    public String username, password;

    public Login(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }
}

Comment: There should be more information in the log cat, not as pretty as normally, but there is more. Please post it, and format it. But I do think that the data binding is searching for a `setUserName` method (in your `Login.class`), which does not exist, throwing an error.

Comment: @Amylinn you are right i made the following changes added the following method to my class

   public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.username);
    }


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.password);
    }
 But it wasnt clear any where that setters are required for 2 way binding . P.S. : How do I add code commenting in comments .

Comment: Put backticks ` around the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment:

> There should be more information in the log cat, not as pretty as normally, but there is more. Please post it, and format it. But I do think that the data binding is searching for a setUserName method (in your Login.class), which does not exist, throwing an error.

The methods should also call `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.propertyName)`, as you correctly mentioned in you comment.

In your `Login.class` add

```
public void setUsername(String username) { 
    this.username = username; 
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.username); 
} 

public void setPassword(String password) { 
    this.password = password; 
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.password); 
}
```